# Types plugin isn't compatible with my custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

I have a website with a few custom post types. I have also installed Types plugin so I can use a custom field to upload/display images on the home page of the website. I've found that the code seems to have an issue with the custom post type.

If I add the code below the custom post type, the image doesn't appear. If I put the code above it, it appears. I have also tried removing the code and it will appear.

```
   <?php $pic_of_week = rg_get_social_pic_of_the_week(); 
                    $url = get_post_meta($pic_of_week['id'], 'social_pic_facebook_url', true);
                ?>

        <a id="social_image" href="<?php echo $url;?>" target="_blank">
            <div id="social_ofweek">
                <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image($pic_of_week['thumbnail'],'social-pic-of-the-week-thumbnail'); ?>
            </div>
            <img id="social_overlay" src="<?php bloginfo(stylesheet_directory); ?>/basemedia/images/socialpic2.png" alt="The Royal George Logo" /> 


        </a>    

    <?php echo(types_render_field("image_1", array("alt"=>"Product image",
  "width"=>"209","height"=>"298","proportional"=>"true"))); ?>
```

The code for the types plugin is -

```
<?php echo(types_render_field("image_1", array("alt"=>"Product image",
  "width"=>"209","height"=>"298","proportional"=>"true"))); ?>
```

The code that seems to be causing the issue is -

```
pic_of_week = rg_get_social_pic_of_the_week(); 
$url = get_post_meta($pic_of_week['id'], 'social_pic_facebook_url', true);
?>
```

Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

Code for rg_get_social_pic_of_the_week() -

```
 if(!function_exists('rg_get_social_pic_of_the_week')) {
    function rg_get_social_pic_of_the_week() {
        global $wp_query;

        $args = array(
            'meta_key' => 'pic_of_the_week',
            'meta_value' => '1',
            'post_type' => 'social-pic'
        );
        $loop = new WP_Query($args);

        $social_pics_array = array();
        while($loop->have_posts()) {
            $loop->the_post();

            $social_pics_array[] = array(
                'content' => get_the_content(),
                'excerpt' => get_the_excerpt(),
                'id' => get_the_ID(),
                'thumbnail' => get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID()),
                'title' => get_the_title()
            );
        }

        if(count($social_pics_array)) {
            return $social_pics_array[0];
        }

        return $social_pics_array;
    }
}
```

Comment: what does the `rg_get_social_pic_of_the_week()` function contain? search your theme or plugins for that function to see what it does.

Comment: Should I post the code for that function?

Comment: I've added the code for the rg_get_social_pic_of_the_week()

Comment: How about a link to the plugin?

Comment: plugin link http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/types/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call [`wp_reset_postdata()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata) after `rg_get_social_pic_of_the_week()`. it runs its own query which is polluting the global `$post` variable that other functions rely on.

Comment: Does that go on the home page or on the functions file?